# Windows appear behind the panel

Tags: 11.04, panel, window

When opening new windows in my Ubuntu 11.04 sometimes they are hidden behind the panel. I can grab them while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Button 1</kbd> but I would like to solve it so that they appear where they should.

The machine where this is happening is an upgraded one and I have seen in several new installations that this is not the expected behaviour.

You can see it in the following link:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: There's a [similar bug in Oneiric](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/857214), but couldn't find anything for Natty. Perhaps you should file a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this too on a machine that was all the way upgraded from Intrepid and the problem did not appear for a dummy new user I created for investigation purposes. This is how I solved it:

I logged out of unity, switched to a virtual terminal hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, logged in as root, killed all remaining processes from my usual login with `killall -u <login>`, did a `cd /home/<login>` and a `mv .gconf .gconf-old`. When logging back in, the issue had disappeared with a lot of others for the price of losing some configurations which I considered a bargain.

After some diffing `.gconf` with `.gconf-old` with `meld`, I reached at the conclusion that some pre-natty compiz settings were the most probable cause, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME. Indeed it could be fixed with compiz:
enable "Place Windows" in Category/Windows Management.

Comment: sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Comment: this is definitly the better answer. fixed it for me o Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

First, install `compizconfig-settings-manager`

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then search **compizconfig-settings-manager** from search panel

[image]

Now scroll down to the opened to the compizconfig window and go to the Window Management

[image]

Enable **Place Windows**