# New windows are placed too high and the window toolbar goes behind the

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, window-manager

I changed some settings in compiz and now the new windows are placed too high and behind the panel. The settings that I changed were disabling the visual effects only. it is really annoying to always drag the windows down. There is a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63190/windows-appear-behind-the-panel) though but no real answer is given.

The same problem also exists with the wallpaper. It is placed behind the panel and you can not see that part of image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if you accidentally disabled the "Place Windows" feature under the "Window Management" settings in ccsm.  I had a similar problem as you, and re-enabling "Place Windows" fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes this works. But do you also have sth to say about the wallpaper that goes behind the panel?